# 3G USB modem recognized but no ttyUSBx device available. Works on one device, fails on 2

Tags: debian, usb, networkmanager, raspbian, 3g

I have three Raspberry Pi 2 devices running up-to-date versions of Raspbian, identically configured with two identical 3G USB modems (ZTE D6601).

On one of them, the modem is made available as a ttyUSB device upon startup and connecting it to the internet (using `nmcli` / Network-Manager) works fine. On the other, it is simply not. I have even re-set up both devices from scratch, interchanged the 3G modems but no success. The device codes as shown in `lsusb` are changed during startup using `usb_modeswitch`.

This is what I am seeing when running `lsusb` and `nmcli dev`:

**Device 1 (ok):**
[image]

**Device 2 (not ok):**
[image]

The `dmesg` outputs are:

**Device 1 (ok):**

```
[   27.705026] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[   27.808010] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=19d2, idProduct=0108
[   27.808040] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
[   27.808057] usb 1-1.4: Product: HSPA WCDMA Technologies MSM
[   27.808073] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: HSPA,Incorporated
[   27.808089] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: MF6670VIED010000
[   27.814276] usb-storage 1-1.4:1.4: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   27.814782] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-1.4:1.4
[   28.000852] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[   28.000985] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[   28.001105] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[   28.069837] usbcore: registered new interface driver option
[   28.070017] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
[   28.070618] option 1-1.4:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   28.071224] usb 1-1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[   28.071564] option 1-1.4:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   28.072078] usb 1-1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[   28.072407] option 1-1.4:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   28.072900] usb 1-1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[   28.073217] option 1-1.4:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   28.073732] usb 1-1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
```

**Device 2 (not ok):**

```
[   17.223150] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[   17.326370] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=19d2, idProduct=0108
[   17.326399] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
[   17.326417] usb 1-1.4: Product: HSPA WCDMA Technologies MSM
[   17.326433] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: HSPA,Incorporated
[   17.326449] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: MF6670VIED010000
*Output stops after this*
```

**My actual question:** Could any of you point me in a new direction of troubleshooting this, please?

Answer (score 1):

The rasberry pi is notoriously underpowered for USB, and a USB 3G modem requires quite a lot of power. It may be that the modem requires just about the amount that an average rpi can deliver, where one can do it but another can't (due to differences that will always happen in manufacturing).

I would suggest that you try hooking the 3G modems up to a powered USB hub; that will probably fix your problem.